# How to force the use of bundled jre with install4j?

Tags: install4j

i'm using the version 6.0.4 of Install4j.

On a Windows 10 (not all), the launcher uses the jre of the computer, not the bundled one, even if the JRE search sequence is empty.

On another computer (win 10 too), if i rename the jre directory ("jre old"), the launcher fails which is what i expect. This is not the behaviour of the previous computer : on it, the launcher succeeds.

Is it possible to force the use of the bundled jre ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independently of the search sequence, the bundled JRE will always be used.

You can check the actual search sequence at runtime by starting the executable from the command line with the argument

```
/create-i4j-log
```

If there is an error with the bundled JRE, it will be shown in the log file.